# Postgres allow english and spanish characters such as: á, ö, ñ, Ñ, etc

Tags: postgresql

Hi anyone knows how I can allow Postgres to support spanish and english characters?

I'm having problems with á, é, í,ó,ú, and ä, ü, ñ, Ñ.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest initializing the database as Unicode character set. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html

Comment: Doesn't it do Unicode by default?

Comment: Have you found any solutions ? I'm having  hard time trying to copying data from a csv to an Unicode database